# subquery delete statement not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know what's wrong with this statement, but whenever i run this i always get an error

here is my sql:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_usersinfo
WHERE users_lname IN
(SELECT users_lname FROM tbl_usersinfo WHERE users_lname = 'asd')
```

here is my error:

#1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl_usersinfo' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: The code should be in subquery.

Comment: I think you don't need to use subquery on that one

Comment: But my prof is requiring us to use subquery. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
DELETE FROM tbl_usersinfo
WHERE users_lname IN
(select * from (SELECT users_lname FROM tbl_usersinfo WHERE users_lname = 'asd') as t)
```

Comment: It works, can you explain why? thanks

Comment: Why is it necessary to have an alias?

Comment: Here explanation
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

NOTE THAT,

`(SELECT users_lname FROM tbl_usersinfo WHERE users_lname = 'asd')`

is equal to

`users_lname='asd'`

So, the sql could be

`DELETE FROM tbl_usersinfo
WHERE users_lname = 'asd'`

Comment: no sir, it should be in subquery.

Comment: why it must be in a subquery? They are equal.

Comment: My prof is requiring us to use subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify target table for delete.

So first create temp table after that use temp table inside the query likewise

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT * FROM tbl_usersinfo)

DELETE FROM tbl_usersinfo
WHERE users_lname IN
(SELECT users_lname FROM table2 WHERE users_lname = 'asd')
```

[Sample Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f4d83/1)

Comment: its not working, here is the error:

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM tbl_usersinfo
WHERE users_lname IN
(SELECT users_lname FROM table2' at line 3

Comment: check my demo @monkeycoder